# Where in macOS High Sierra is the "Updates Installed in the Last 30 Days" information from the App Store stored?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, high-sierra

In macOS **Sierra** this information was stored in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/App Store/updatejournal.plist
```

But in macOS **High Sierra** this file only contains the 3rd Party Apps from the App Store. The Update Information from Apple Updates is apparently stored somewhere else

Is there a second file somewhere else, or where is this information now stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s in a different location now:

`/private/var/db/softwareupdate/journal.plist`

Don't forget to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

General System Updates but also Updates from Apple Products like Xcode for example can be found at 
/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist